# Side Drawer Filter

Tags: web-app, filter, drawer

I have a right side drawer on a web application, but there are filters for each section. The filters include: 'Is equal to', 'Is not equal to', 'Array Contains', and 'Array does not contain'. Then the user can enter an integer in the input field. The user can add multiple filters, delete/cancel filters, and save created filters. What is a good way to display this?
[image: Data Table]
[image: Data Table Selected]
[image: Side drawer filter]

Comment: Can you show what you tried with additional images? And can you share the problem with your current design attempts? If the question is just how to design this, it is not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So the problem I am solving for is a data table that has over 50 columns. To decrease the extensive vertical scrolling from the user. I created a drawer (because the user has to select the a column for interactions). My problem is showing the filters which was previously a modal when triggered. I can add additional screens

Comment: Do you mean to ask that each column in the table has filters and what would be the best way to display the filters for each column, given that there are 50 columns in the table?

Comment: @EricChia yes thats correct

Comment: Ok, assuming that each column has unique filters and each filter is customisable by the user, the one that you currently have, i.e. either a side drawer or modal, in my opinion, is the best way of presenting the filters. You can improve the experience by inserting accelerators to help users customise the filters faster.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for the feedback this is very helpful